# Поставить лайк ютуб, используя cookies через Leaf.Xnet

Tags: c#, youtube

Захожу на страницу видео, заранее импортировав cookies в запрос.

Подскажите, как поставить лайк на видео: youtube api авторизацию почему-то не воспринимает и выкидывает ошибку 401.

Comment: Вы используете какое-то готовое api на C# или сами пишите?

Comment: 401 - это не про куки, а про отсутствие HTTP заголовка Authorization.